# Run cuda program using php, report no CUDA capable devices were detected

Tags: php, apache, web, service, cuda

I use `shell_exec($command)` running CUDA program,but report `*no CUDA capable devices were detected*.`

I had echo `$command`. I ran the command on my terminal and it successed.

I guess that the problem may because of lacking of system environment(`PATH` ,etc.).
I had added something on `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` as follow:

```
#cuda 6.5
SetEnv PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

After I restarted the apache2 service, `*no CUDA capable devices were detected*`.

What is the problem on my program?

Comment: PHP runs scripts as the webserver user. Maybe it needs more permissions?

Comment: I had change my permission of CUDA program as 777.

Comment: I don't think that solves anything. The problem isn't that the webserver user can't run the script, it's probably that the script uses functions for which it needs more permissions (like looking for devices). That would be my guess at least.

Answer (score 1):

Thank for Halcyon's advice.
I try that add www-data account to /etc/sudoers with No-Password, and add "sudo" before $command. It work perfact.